# Where to see suggested edits

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Where can I see suggested edits of other users? Is there a place where all suggested edits (that are yet to approve) listed ?

Answer (score 1):

We can find the reviews in https://stackoverflow.com/review/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) privilege (reputation >= 2000), you can see and review the proposed edits [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits).